# Export richtextbox to pdf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I would like to export the contents of a `RichTextBox` with `InlineUIContainer` inside to pdf format or rtf or doc. I just need it to export but i keep getting a blank document. I've been stuck on this problem for days. Please help. Its similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17789052/export-flowdocument-with-uielement-to-rtf) i asked earlier

Comment: Would saving it as RTF work?

Comment: No, it did not work. If I put text in the paragraph of the FlowDocument, it shows but the contents of the InlineUIContainer do not show

Comment: Then i don't know what to do. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

OK, finally got it. All i had to do was set the Width and Height of the InlineUIContainer explicitly.

Comment: Could you kindly share your solution on github:)